# Proving that dim $\cap_{i=1}^m N(\phi_i)=\dim V-n$, where $V$ is a finite dimensional vector space and $\phi_i$'s are L.I. in $V'$.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space over field $F$. Let $\phi_1, \phi_2,\ldots,\phi_m$  be linearly independent (L.I.) in $V'$, the space of all linear functionals on $V$.  Let's denote nullspace of linear map $A$ by $N(A)$ and dimension of space $S$ by $D(S)$. Then it is to be proven that $$D(\cap_{i=1}^m N(\phi_i))=D(V)-m$$

I tried to prove it like this:

Let $W:=\cap_{i=1}^m N(\phi_i)$. For any $1\le i\le m$,  for all $w\in W$, $\phi_i(w)=0$ whence it follows that $\phi_i$'s belong to annhilator space of $W$ that is $\{\phi_i: 1\le i \le m\}\subset W^0$. It follows that $D(W^0)\ge m\implies D(V)-D(W)\ge m\implies D(W)\le D(V)-m$

I don't know how to show that $D(W)\ge D(V)-m$.

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One simple approach to the problem is to consider the map $\Phi:V \to F^m$ given by
$$
\Phi(v) = (\phi_1(v),\dots,\phi_m(v)).
$$
Verify that $\bigcap_{i=1}^m N(\phi_i) = N(\Phi)$. Because the $\phi_i$ are linearly independent, we can conclude that $\Phi$ is surjective. From there, we conclude that $\dim N(\Phi) = \dim(V) - m$ by the rank-nullity theorem.

---

Alternatively, let $\Psi: V \to V''$ denote the canonical identification of $V$ with $V''$ defined by
$$
\Psi(v)(\phi) = \phi(v).
$$
Show that $\Psi(W) = S^{0}$. Thus, we have
$$
\dim(W) = \dim(\Psi(W)) = \dim(S^0) = \dim(V') - \dim(S) = \dim(V) - m.
$$

Comment: +1 Thank you so much. :)

Comment: I have one small confusion: I don't understand how linear independence of $\{\phi_i\}$'s imply that $\Phi$ is surjective. Please help me understand that. Thanks.

Comment: Never mind, I got my answer now. :)

Comment: @Koro Note that if $\Phi$ fails to be surjective if and only if there is a non-zero column-vector $c$ such that for all $v\in V,$ $c^T\Phi(v)=0$.

Comment: I’m afraid I don’t understand why “$\Phi$ fails to be surjective if and only if…”. But I do see that existence of such column vector c is impossible in this case because if $\sum c_i \phi_i(v)=0 $ for all v then $\sum c_i\phi_i=0$ whence by LI nature of $\phi_i$’s, we get $c_i=0$. Can you please help me understand how you made such strong/big observation/claim that “$\Phi$ is surjective iff…” with such ease?

Comment: What I understood was that: if U is a proper subspace of finite dimensional vector space V then we can find a linear functional on V such that its kernal (null space) is U. Using this, if on the contrary $\Phi(V)$ were a proper subspace of $F^m$ then we should be able to find a non zero linear functional on $F^m$ but it can be shown to be false using linear independence of $\phi_i$’s. Therefore, $\Phi$ must be surjective.

Comment: @Koro That's exactly right. Note that every functional on $F^m$ has the form $\phi(x) = c^Tx$ for some $c \in F^m$.

Comment: Noted. But while writing that comment "Φ fails to be surjective if and only if...", is this what you had in mind that is, the theorem I stated in my last comment above? Or did you have anything else in mind? Please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: @Koro The theorem you stated is what I had in mind

Comment: Ok. I understood now. Thank you so much. :)